# What regression approach does tensorflow's DNNRegressor apply under the hood?

Tags: machine-learning, python, deep-learning, tensorflow, regression

I want to understand what kind of regression does the DNNRegressor estimator apply in the background, specifically is it linear?

Comment: Have a look at the source code